# JSP like templating for simple text

Tags: java, jsp, text-files, template-engine

I've got a program that currently has a mass of code that I would like to design away.  This code takes a number of text files and passes it through an interestingly written interpreter to produce a plain text file report that goes on to other systems.  In *theory* this allows a non-programmer to be able to modify the report without having to understand the inner workings of Java and the interpreter.  In practice, any minor change likely necessitates going into the interpreter and tweaking it (and the domain specific language isn't exactly friendly even to other programmers).

I would love to redesign this code.  As a primarily web programmer the first thing that came to mind when thinking of "non-programmer being able to modify the report ..." I replaced report with web page and said to myself "ah ha! Jsp."  This would give me a nice What You See Is Almost What You Get approach for people along with taglibs and java scriptlets (as undesirable as the later may be) rather than awkwardly written DSL statements.

While it is possible to use `jspc` to compile a jsp into java (another part of the application runs ejbs on a jboss server so `jspc` isn't too far away), the boilerplate code that it uses tries to hook up the output to the pagecontext from the servletcontext.  It would involve tricking the code into thinking it was running inside a web container (not an impossibility, but a kluge) and then removing the headers.

Is there a different templateing approach (or library) for java that could be used to print to a text file?  Every one that I've looked at so far appears to either be optimized for web or tightly coupled to a particular application server (and designed for web work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need a slim down version of JSP.

See if this one (JSTP) works for you

http://jstp.sourceforge.net/manual.html

Answer (score 3):

Give [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org) a try. It is incredibly simple and does not assume it is running in the context of a web application.

This is totally subjective, but I would argue it's syntax is easier for a non-programmer to understand than JSP and tag libraries.

Comment: For reference for myself and any future readers, [velocity engine user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html)

Comment: non-programmers will never write any templates. programmers have to do everything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be a real tread setter in your company, you could create a Grails application to do it and use Groovy templating (maybe in combination with the Quartz plugin for scheduling), it might be a bit of a hard sell if there is alot of existing code to be replaced but I love it...

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates

If you want the safe bet, then (the also excellent) Velocity has to be it:

http://velocity.apache.org/

Comment: This report is generated out of the innards of a very large java application.  Moving it out of the innards of this application isn't an option.

Comment: In Grails you can also write Java (not just Groovy) but I get your point.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to check [**Rythm template engine**](http://rythmengine.com/), with good performance (2 to 3 times faster than velocity) and elegant syntax (.net Razor like) and designed specifically to Java programmer.

**Template, generate a string of user names separated by "," from a list of users**

```
@args List<User> users

@for (User user: users) {
   @user.getName() @user_sep
}
```

**Template: if-else demo**

```
@args User user

@if (user.isAdmin()) {
   <div id="admin-panel">...</div>
} else {
   <div id="user-panel">...</div>
}
```

**Invoke template using template file**

```
// pass render args by name
Map<String, Object> renderArgs = ...
String s = Rythm.render("/path/to/my/template.txt", renderArgs);

// or pass render arguments by position
String s = Rythm.render("/path/to/my/template.txt", "arg1", 2, true, ...);
```

**Invoke template using inline text**

```
User user = ...;
String s = Rythm.render("@args User user;Hello @user.getName()", user);
```

**Invoke template with String interpolation mode**

```
User user = ...;
String s = Rythm.render("Hello @name", user.getName());
```

**ToString mode**

```
public class Address {
   public String unitNo;
   public String streetNo;
   ...
   public String toString() {
      return Rythm.toString("@_.unitNo @_.streetNo @_.street, @_.suburb, @_.state, @_.postCode", this);
   }
}
```

**Auto ToString mode** (follow apache commons lang's reflectionToStringBuilder, but faster than it)

```
public class Address {
   public String unitNo;
   public String streetNo;
   ...
   public String toString() {
      return Rythm.toString(this);
   }
}
```

Document could be found at http://www.playframework.org/modules/rythm. Full demo app running on GAE: http://play-rythm-demo.appspot.com.

Note, the demo and doc are created for play-rythm plugin for Play!Framework, but most of the content also apply to the pure rythm template engine.

Source code:

- Rythm template engine: https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm/
- Play Rythm Plugin: https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-rythm